# Hidden quotes with code formatting are broken on beta sites

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown, code-formatting, blockquote

> The quick `brown` fox jumped over the lazy [dog](http://dog.com).

The `code formatting background` only displays when you have clicked on it and it is on always "visible" mode.

The text that is code blocks (fixed width) disappears before the main text. They do the same fading in - they appear immediately (first 3 frames of my screencast, vs first ~15).

[image]

Here I click the quote box. The `code formatting` appears, and the link stops being underlined, and starts being proper link style - no underline, change colour on hover.

[image]

The code blocks applies to the design on beta sites - [see here for example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4767), and the links fades wrong here too.

Chrome 39 and Firefox 34 on Ubuntu 14.04, and Chrome 39 on Windows 7.

So... It would be nice if the code blocks and urls displayed correctly on the fade in block without clicking and if they faded in at a better speed...

Comment: No-repro on your first fading issue in Firefox and Chrome on Windows 7. Fades in and out perfectly with no oddities past your second issue.

Comment: @animuson yep, only beta sites, my mistake!

Comment: Ah yeah, I see it now. I assumed since MSE used the same styles that the spoilers worked the same here.

Comment: I thought they did at first too which is why my attempts at repro in the MSE sandbox confused me... :)